# How to handle event in flask-socketio?

Tags: python, reactjs, events, socket.io, flask-socketio

Part which sends data(.js): (this work fine because I print json in python)

[image]

Client how have to receive the data(.js):
[image]

And python how has event and handle it(py).

[image]

Workflow of actions:

sendMessage emit json_ to set_iot_const

.py file hadnle that event and print properly _json and he has to emit('first_event'..)

first_event will be handled in middle picture. (socket.on('fitst_event'...)

I don't know why, but 'first_event' like never execute ? Any suggestion why and how to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, broadcast is misspelt as broadcats. This could be the reason why 'first_event' is never triggered.